# ADB no device Nexus 5

Tags: adb, nexus-5, lineageos

On my Nexus 5 (LineageOS 15.1 / Android 8.1) i can't see my device when typing "adb devices" (manjaro with Android SDK 3.2.1). What I tried:

1. root access: "ADB only"
2. android debugging: "on"
3. revoked usb authorizations
4. usb configuration: "MIDI"/"AUDIO"/"Charging"/"MTP"/"PTP" (tried each)
5. restarted device connected and also connect after restart was done
6. changed USB Cable
7. inserted udev rules (like on [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android_Debug_Bridge#Adding_udev_Rules))
8. all of this in a root shell

"lsusb" is not listing the device if I have android debugging on. If it's off i see it. (as soon as i switch it on it disappears).
I don't have Windows at the time, so would this help?

**What can I try next?**

My goal was to install ubuntu touch in dual boot mode.